# Nested quantifier * exception with C# regex matching US phone number

Tags: c#, regex

The following expression is supposed to match US phone numbers:

```
\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}
```

However, when I use it in my program it thows an error:

> parsing "(?\d{3})?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}" - Nested quantifier *.

I just can't see where the error is. :(

It works well with [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/xW7rB5/1) for:

```
(111) 111-1111
111-111-1111
1111111111
```

but does not seem to work when used with C# Regex.

I appreciate any guidance. TIA

(C# VS2010 .NET 4.0)

Edit:
    This fixes the problem:

```
 \(?\d{3}\)?-?\s*\d{3}-?\s*-?\d{4}
```

Still don't know why there was a Nested quantifier error though?

Comment: try `@"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj The string wouldn't even compile if it wasn't a verbatim already. Maybe it's not in the source though...

Comment: Downvoters care to comment?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Tried.. no luck??

Comment: maybe replace space (' ') with `\s` to be sure there is a character, or `*` with {0,}. What result it would give?

Comment: @m.cekiera The \s was the solution. Still don't know why the nested quantifier error (or the downvote) though. Thanks.

Comment: and if you replece again `\s` with space, the problem appear again? most propable, ther was no space between `?` and `*`

Comment: Did you use `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`? It could be the culprit.  See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c(%3f%5cd%7b3%7d%5c)%3f-%3f+*%5cd%7b3%7d-%3f+*-%3f%5cd%7b4%7d&i=(111)+111-1111%0d%0a111-111-1111%0d%0a1111111111), uncheck the Ignore Whitespace option to repro.

Comment: You need to use \\ to escape \ special meaning  in C# literals. Let us see your pattern in C# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your first regex is that it contains literal spaces that are ignored when using `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` option. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c(%3f%5cd%7b3%7d%5c)%3f-%3f+*%5cd%7b3%7d-%3f+*-%3f%5cd%7b4%7d&i=(111)+111-1111%0d%0a111-111-1111%0d%0a1111111111), *check* the `Ignore Whitespace` option to reproduce the issue.

Your first regex is thus equal to

```
\(?\d{3}\)?-?*\d{3}-?*-?\d{4}
             ^       ^
```

To make this regex work, do not use the `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` option, or the `*` quantifier will be applied to the `?` quantifier which is not allowed in .NET regex.

Or replace the spaces with `[ ]`, or `\s`. E.g.

```
\(?\d{3}\)?-?[ ]*\d{3}-?[ ]*-?\d{4}
```

The space inside a character class is not ignored when using `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` flag (see [*RegexOptions Enumeration* MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.100).aspx)).

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C(%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C)%3F-%3F%5B%20%5D*%5Cd%7B3%7D-%3F%5B%20%5D*-%3F%5Cd%7B4%7D&i=(111)%20111-1111%0D%0A111-111-1111%0D%0A1111111111&o=x)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Regex RegexObj = new Regex("\\(?\\d{3}-?\\)?\\s*\\d{3}-?\\s*-?\\d{4}");
            String Str1 = "(111) 111-1111";
            String Str2 = "111-111-1111";
            String Str3 = "1111111111";
            Console.Write(RegexObj.IsMatch(Str1).ToString() + '\n');
            Console.Write(RegexObj.IsMatch(Str2).ToString() + '\n');
            Console.Write(RegexObj.IsMatch(Str3).ToString() + '\n');


            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]